# eclipsefp and yesod :installed package was not recognized

Tags: haskell, yesod, eclipse-fp

## error info from eclipse

> At least the following dependencies are missing: hspec -any,
> yesod-test ==1.4.*

but after install these packs,the issue remains

i reinstalled eclipsefp,yesod,buildwrapper,hoogle,scion-browser,no help.

build yesod project with cabal install in terminal succeeded.

## environment

eclipsefp newest(2.6.1)

yesod newest 1.4.0.2

eclipse luna

oracle jre 8u25

ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you install the packages with by running `cabal install` (without any other arguments)? That wouldn't have installed the testing packages. If so, try `cabal install --enable tests` (or `yesod test` which I think does that for you). http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved! the workspace (mostly .metadate) is broken
i create a new workspace and create a new yesod project,no more errors

Comment: I can see how this isn't a great answer, but if the workspace is borked then recreating it is the correct course of action and there really isn't much more to be said. If anything probably the question should be removed for off-topic/can no longer be reproduced.